# Динамическое создание Expression для типа DateTime

Tags: c#, рефлексия, expressions

Есть класс Orders:

```
class Orders
{
   public DateTime StartDate  { get; set; }
}
```

Есть также выражение:

```
...<Orders>(o => o.StartDate < DateTime.Now.Date)
```

т.е. отбираются заявки, у которых StartDate < текущей даты

Я создаю динамическое выражение, которое заменяет лямбду (o => o.StartDate < DateTime.Now.Date):

```
Type tType = typeof(T); //typeof(Orders)
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(tType, tType.FullName);
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "StartDate");

ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now.Date);

Expression expression = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constant);
```

и так далее

главное, что property здесь указывает на свойство StartDate класса Orders.

Но если лямбду заменить на такую:

```
...<Orders>(o => o.StartDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
```

т.е. из даты-времени свойства StartDate берется только составляющая даты.

Как реализовать это при создании динамического выражения?

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131182/how-generate-dynamic-expression-for-date-time-filed-in-c-sharp) человек задавал аналогичный вопрос, который, к сожалению, остался без ответа.

Comment: Почему у вас нет никаких проблем с обращением к свойству StartDate, но есть проблемы с обращением к свойству Date?

Comment: `MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "StartDate"), "Date");`

Comment: Потому что если я пишу 

MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "StartDate.Date");

то во время выполнения выбрасывается исключение

"System.ArgumentException: Instance property 'StartDate.Date' is not defined for type 'InfoSys.Index.DataAccess.LinqToDb.Models.Orders

Comment: Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "StartDate"), "Date");
Это да, должно сработать, я что-то не додумал так сделать. Всем спасибо.